# Project reference not working from team build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, biztalk

I have a VS2010 BizTalk solution. This contains schemas project that has a reference to another schemas project.

I am able to build the solution from VS2010 no problem. However, when the nightly team build runs I get a the error *Schema reference "x.int.common.schemas.canonical.types is not a valid reference or does not exist in the current project*

I've opened the solution from the nightly build folder. I can see that the project reference does exist and all looks good.

I have checked the GAC and can confirm there's no sign of any of my assemblies.

I have run a text compare on the parent project file from both my manual build version and the nightly build version - they are identical.

I check the folder of the nightly build and under the \bin of the \sources\parent project, I can see that it has successfully copied the child assembly.

I've run out of ideas as to why the automated team build would not be able to resolve the project reference. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried adding the reference to the assembly via the 'browse' tab instead of the 'projects' tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to resolve this was to re-boot the build server

Comment: I've found over the years that when Biztalk is running it is fantastic, but when it is doing weird stuff then the first thing to do is reboot.